# add a service name to sns transmission

Tags: go, sms, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to achieve it using aws-sdk-go while creating an application that sends sms with golang

I'm successful in sending sms but have trouble getting service names(This is the part that shows where you are coming from)

※ It is currently called NOTICE

Below is the code that implements sms transmission

```
    input := &sns.PublishInput{
        Message:     aws.String("your auth code is" + code + "thats expire at 15 min"),
        PhoneNumber: aws.String(phone),
    }

    _, err = svc.Publish(input)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("auth code send sms error: %w", err)
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

aws sns service for telephone numbers in Japan
Didn't seem to support displaying SenderID

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html